# How do I update node.js to a specific version on Windows?

Tags: node.js, installation, upgrade

I have node version 6.11.3 installed.
I need to install 8.11.3 on windows.  I just can't find anything that works.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest option is to just download the appropriate `.msi` installer (x64 or x86) for the desired version. With each downloaded update, the newer versions will replace the older version. So for 8.11.3 you'd use https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.11.3/

List of all versions can be found here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

---

However, if you want to be more flexible, you can give the windows version of NVM (node version manager) a try:

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: Oh, would this be the right file for Windows 10?  "node-v8.11.3-win-x64.zip"

Comment: Thank you.  That worked. A few notes.  This is the url I went to:
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.11.3/

This is the the file I used for the msi install package on Windows 10: node-v8.11.3-x64.msi 

Interesting fact.  If you go and watch the "C:\Program Files" folder during the install, you will see the node.js folder dissapear and reappear so you can be comfortable in knowing you are getting a clean new version.  The run node -v again to see "8.11.3"

Comment: @Sam Yep exactly! Glad I could help :)